# Why do the results of LASSO regression differ after removing uninformative variables in glmnet?

Tags: r, feature-selection, lasso, caret, glmnet

I am researching therapy response of melanoma patients based on a number of approximately 80 features with a very small sample size of 60 patients. To eliminate features that do not contribute to the model, I am using `train` from the `caret` package and `glmnet` with alpha = 1 to perform LASSO regression. This leads to 4 features being kept in the model and an AUC of 0.72. Out of curiosity I fit the model again using only these 4 features and I get an AUC of 0.85. I thought that by using LASSO regression uninformative variables were set to zero and removed from the model so the results should be the same as when just fitting the 4 remaining features. Is there something I am missing about this approach?

````
cctrl1 <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10, returnResamp="all",
                       classProbs=TRUE, summaryFunction=twoClassSummary)

# create model matrix with all features
x <- model.matrix(Responder ~ ,data=df)
x <- x[,-1]

set.seed(849)
test_class_cv_model <- train(x, df$Responder, method = "glmnet", 
                             trControl = cctrl1,metric = "ROC",
                             tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 1,
                                                    lambda = seq(0.001,0.2,by = 0.001)))

# extracting maximum AUC
max(test_class_cv_model$results$ROC)
[1] 0.7180556

# identify remaining features
coef(test_class_cv_model$finalModel, test_class_cv_model$finalModel$lambdaOpt)



# generate model matrix with the 4 remaining features
xfeat <- model.matrix(Responder ~ F1 + F2 + F3 + F4,data=df)
xfeat <- xfeat[,-1]

set.seed(849)
test_class_cv_model_feat <- train(xfeat, df$Responder, method = "glmnet", 
                             trControl = cctrl1,metric = "ROC",
                             tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 1,
                                                    lambda = seq(0.001,0.2,by = 0.001)))

# extracting maximum AUC
max(test_class_cv_model_feat$results$ROC)
[1] 0.8472222
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re using different loss functions. Of course they’re different. When you do the LASSO, the variables that get set to zero contribute to the loss function. When you do OLS on the “surviving” variables, the loss function only ever sees those variables.

In LASSO, the loss function sees the "dead" variables and has an opportunity to keep them from having their coefficients estimated as nonzero. Once you eliminate those variables, however, then you are essentially forcing those features to have coefficients of zero no matter what.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. However, two things are still not clear for me as an ML beginner.  1. How do the variables set to zero still contribute to the loss function? In my understand lambda is multiplied with the absolute value of each parameter so if a parameter is shrunk to 0, how does it still affect the function?

Comment: 2. Is it a valid approach to use LASSO for feature selection and then use glmnet with the 4 "surviving" features? I have seen an example where LASSO is used preliminary to multiple regression but could not find anything for logistic regression.  And a third thing came to my mind: why do you refer to OLS when lambda is > 0 and not also LASSO?

Comment: #2 is a second question to ask, and I suspect it has been covered in accepted answers; please do a search. Regarding #1, the coefficients got to be zero by the way the LASSO loss function is optimized, not by human intervention and saying, “You will be zero no matter what.”

Comment: I have searched but could not find anything regarding #2 so I will open a separate thread

Answer (score 2):

Define a covariate matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ with columns $\{x_j\}$, where there are $n$ observations of $p$ covariates. Define the response $y \in \mathbb{R}^p$. Suppose we are interested in recovering the linear coefficients $\beta$ of $y$ when regressed on $\{x_j\}$.

The Lasso estimator with tuning parameter $\lambda \geq 0$ is defined as: $$\hat\beta_\lambda = \arg\min_{\beta} \|y-X\beta\|_2^2 + \lambda \|\beta\|_1.$$ Define the associated support as $\hat{S}_{\lambda} = \{ j \in \{1, \dots, p\} \, : \, \hat\beta_{\lambda, j} \neq 0 \}$, the covariate indices whose estimated coefficient $\hat\beta_{\lambda, j}$ is nonzero.

Let us define another estimator which performs the lasso only on the support $\hat{S}_\lambda$, ignoring the coefficients not selected by the Lasso: $$\hat\alpha_\lambda = \arg\min_{\alpha} \left\|y- \sum_{j \in \hat{S}_\lambda} x_j \alpha_j \right\|_2^2 + \lambda \sum_{j \in \hat{S}_\lambda} |\alpha_j|.$$ An interesting identity holds: $\hat{\beta}_{\lambda, j} = \hat{\alpha}_{\lambda, j}$ whenever $j \in \hat{S}_\lambda$. This says that the coefficients agree on $\hat{S}_\lambda$ regardless of whether the covariates in $\hat{S}_\lambda^C$ are included in the regression. Why is this true? It follows from a one line proof: the Lasso finds the coefficient estimates which minimize its objective, and the objective for $\hat\alpha_\lambda$ is the same.

This shows that Dave's argument concerning the covariates $j \not\in \hat{S}_\lambda$ being included in the objective must be wrong. However, it also reveals the real reason. The coefficients $\hat\alpha_\lambda$ are being penalized! The term ``$\lambda \sum_{j \in \hat{S}_\lambda} |\alpha_j|$'' induces shrinkage whenever $\lambda > 0$. It makes sense that these coefficients $\hat\alpha_\lambda$ disagree with the OLS coefficients on $\hat{S}_\lambda$. (Note, this latter method is called the relaxed lasso.)

Comment: I do not follow your criticism of my stance that all covariates contribute to the optimization of the LASSO loss function. // It sounds like you're arguing that running OLS on the surviving variables gives the same estimates as you get from the LASSO, which is not correct.

Comment: @Dave That's not what I'm arguing. What makes you say that it is?

Comment: "This says that the coefficients agree on $\hat S_{\lambda}$ regardless of whether the covariates in $\hat S_{\lambda}^C$ are included in the regression."

Comment: @Dave Thanks for including a reference. That's referring to the regression on the previous line, which has a penalty. The objective function would be OLS if the penalty were removed. Since the penalty is there, it's Lasso on a reduced set of variables.

Comment: This seems circular. You wind up with the same parameter estimates whether you include the “dead” variables or not (assuming the same penalty), but you still had to know to exclude those variables, which you knew because of the optimization when the “dead” variables were considered.

Comment: @Dave That's directional, not circular. There's no loop back. The point is to clearly introduce an intermediate estimator between Lasso and OLS.  This isolates the impact of removing the variables and of removing the penalty. What do we learn? Removing the variables has absolutely no impact. Removing the penalty does have an impact. Therefore, "Lasso" and "OLS on the selected set" are different because of shrinkage (due to the penalty), not because of removing the non-selected covariates.

Answer (score 0):

The training of the LASSO model is not only selecting features but also restricting the magnitude of the coefficients.

It can be (and often is) that the LASSO model finds some optimum that is restricted by the addition of non-informative features to the model (features that would fit the noise and generalize bad and perform bad). If the parameter for the penalty term would be further decreased then more (bad) features will be included.

(So it can be that your LASSO model is 'wrongly' restricting the magnitude of the coefficients for the included correct features, because it has to keep the number of features low)

Without those other features you will get that the LASSO model is able place the optimum at a different place and increase the magnitude of the coefficients of the four features (without those other features being included).

A similar thing happens when you perform OLS with the features selected by LASSO. You will in general get larger coefficients that may potentially give a better model.